# Chat is working but does some weird things

Tags: android, chat, android-adapter

I implemented a chat where the messages of the current user are at the right and the other users' messages are on the left. Everything is working fine, but if I write more than +- 10 messages to the user, some message bubbles changes randomly the side (mostly from the left to the right). If I close the chat activity a go back, they are back in their original position, and if I write a message again, they start changing their side over again.

Here is my function from the adapter where I decide which message I put left an which right.
I have a chatList where all messanges are saved and getCurrentUser is a boolean where it returns true if the messange is from the current user and false if not.

Thanks for any answer.

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChatViewHolders holder, int position) {

        holder.mMessage.setText(chatList.get(position).getMessage());

        if(chatList.get(position).getCurrentUser()){
            holder.mMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_round);
            holder.mMessage.setGravity(Gravity.END);
            holder.mContainer.setGravity(Gravity.END);
            holder.mMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }else {
            holder.mMessage.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            holder.mMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

            }
```